# requirements.txt: conditional on python version

Tags: python, dependency-management, requirements.txt

My requirements.txt has got `dataclasses` in it, to backport for python 3.6

However, some build machines and coworkers use python 3.7, which fails when it attempts to install this module.

Is there a way to make dataclasses only installed if it is necessary?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with supporting multiple versions of Python and having different dependencies for each, but: "However, some build machines and coworkers use python 3.7"—why wouldn't your build machines and development machines all be using the same version of Python?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Environmental Markers

```
dataclasses; python_version < '3.7'
```

Reference: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#environment-markers